# Variables don't hold value for very long pymongo ipython

Tags: pymongo

Perhaps I should just restart my computer, but it seems my variable are losing their values. A simple aggregation only seems to hold the contents of my database for a short period of time. Note: I'm doing this in an ipython notebook.

```
MONGODB_URI ='mongodb://username:password@***.mongolab.****/***'
client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
db = client.get_default_database()
collectn = db.collection_name

pipe = [
    {"$unwind":"$predictions"},
    {"$match": {"predictions.t_obj": datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 29, 11, 0)}}
]
should_be_data = collectn.aggregate(pipe)
list(should_be_data)
// returns what we expect, i.e. data

list(should_be_data)
// returns []
```

Why do the contents of my variable disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`should_be_data` isn't a list/data-container, but a *generator*.

The first time you run `list(should_be_data)`, the generator is consumed completely.  This lines consumed the elements from the generator, and stores them in a new list.

By the second time you run `list(should_be_data)`, the generator is already exhaused, thus it returns no further elements.

If you want it to be a list to begin with, just replace

```
should_be_data = collectn.aggregate(pipe)
```

with

```
should_be_data = list(collectn.aggregate(pipe))
```